# Check if a task is waiting or busy

Tags: c#, synchronization, task, simulation, blocking

Given a list of tasks, how can I check whether all those tasks are currently waiting, or busy doing calculations?

By "waiting" I mean that the task will not continue until something else changes: The task is stuck on `await otherTask` or `await semaphore.AsyncWaitHandle()`, etc.

This is for a [discrete event simulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_event_simulation).

Below is an example of what I am trying to do: I want to simulate some jobs (t1, t2, t3) that share resources and take some time to complete.

So t1 and t2 share resources, and cannot run at the same time. t3 requires t1 to be complete.

In the real world those tasks would take hours, and I could simply simulate this with Task.Delay(), but I do not want to wait that long.

So whenever *all* tasks are blocked, I want to fast-forward the time.
So I need something other than Task.Delay(), to release a task if all tasks are blocked.

```
public static async Task MainAsync()
{
    Task t1 = Screw1(), t2=Screw2(), t3 = ThightenBolts1(t1);
    await Task.WhenAll(t1,t2,t3); // this takes 6 hours :(
}

// There is only one screwdriver for everyone
static SemaphoreSlim screwdriver = new SemaphoreSlim(1,1);

static async Task Screw1()
{
    await screwdriver.WaitAsync();
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromHours(1));
    Console.WriteLine("Item 1 screwed.");
    screwdriver.Release();
}
static async Task Screw2()
{
    await screwdriver.WaitAsync();
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromHours(2));
    Console.WriteLine("Item 2 screwed.");
    screwdriver.Release();
}
static async Task ThightenBolts1(Task prevTask)
{
    await prevTask;
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromHours(3));
    Console.WriteLine("Item 1 thightened.");
}
```

This simulation would take 6 hours to complete. Most of the time, all tasks are blocked, waiting for simulated time to pass.
So I want to fast-forward, but only if no task is currently running some calculations.

To do that, I need to detect that all the tasks are waiting for something, and not busy calculating. Then I could implement a version of Task.Delay(), which continues the next task earlier.

Comment: What mechanism do the tasks use to block?

Comment: No, there is no standard way to do it. You have to look at cancellation by timeout or exception, for example.

Comment: You both shouldn't be using the task constructor *ever*, and shouldn't be creating threads that run code on the thread pool only to have them sit there doing nothing waiting for some operation to finish.  Do the work asynchronously.  Have them *asynchronously* wait for various other operations to finish, so that they're not needlessly blocking a thread pool thread for the duration.

Comment: @servy I wanted to keep the example as simple as possible. The same code is possible with async / await, and without using threads, but the same problem remains: I want to detect when all the tasks are unable to continue until some time has passed, and then fast-forward. The goal is to simulate a real-world process. The tasks themselves will never do any meaningfull work; the goal is to find out how long the real-world process would take.

Comment: @servy I rewrote the example as per your suggestion using async, hopefully now my intention is clearer. The basic problem remains.

Answer (score -3):

You can use await to wait until the task is completed and then start the next task.

```
public async void starttasks()
    {
        await Task.Run(() => {  /* your code */  } );  //Task1
        await Task.Run(() => {  /* your code */  } );  //Task2
        await Task.Run(() => {  /* your code */  } );  //Task3
        await Task.Run(() => {  /* your code */  } );  //Task4 
        await Task.Run(() => {  /* your code */  } );  //Task5
    }
```

This will execute the 1st task and wait for it to complete to execute the next one, respectively.
I Hope this helps you.

You can also add task.delay after the code i provided above to wait after all task are completed.

```
await Task.Delay(5000);
```

Comment: I know how to wait until some tasks are completed (either `async Task.WhenAll()` or `Task.WaitAll()`, but I only want to wait until all tasks are **blocked** (actively consuming processor time)